# Xcode 7 Swift 2 - Move button within a specific view area

Tags: button, view, move, area, bounds

I would like to move a button's position (X & Y) within a specific area of a view object.

What I've done so far is, I've added a view object on to my main screen and I've also added a button inside the view, so far OK.

Now, I managed to get the bounds of the view object and I know the size of my button say (50x50). So what I want is, when I click on the button, it should move to another random location but within the view object, it should not move outside the view object boundaries. Right now what happens in my button appears to be moving a portion of it outside the view object based on the random X & Y.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I have manged to get it done.

Comment: I am attempting to figure out the exact same thing, can you please post your solution.

Comment: @Lkabo I shall post the code soon, I gathered the solution from the net.

Comment: @Lkabo I'm trying to paste the code but I don't know how to get it in code mode... its not showing as code but as a paragraph. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it as well. Here is how I did it:

I created a function which I pass the shape to and return the location that I want the piece to move to which is within the bounds of the view.

```
    func randomizeLocation(shape: CGRect) -> CGPoint {


    let randomX = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(gameBoard.frame.width - shape.width)) + UInt32(shape.width / 2)
    let randomY = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(gameBoard.frame.height - shape.height)) + UInt32(shape.height / 2)



    return CGPointMake(CGFloat(randomX), CGFloat(randomY))
}
```

Just in speaking about the x coordinate (left/right)
The logic here is that arc4random_uniform will return a random # between 0 and the given number (- 1).

But you don't want a number starting at zero because that would put the object off the edge of the screen to the left by 1/2. So, if you add 1/2 of the width to the overall function, you will never go off to the left side of the screen.

To keep from going off the right side of the screen you want a maximum number of the screen width minus 1/2 of the width of the object. To get this, you must specify the number you pass to the arc4random function as minus the **whole** width of the shape, **because when you add back half, you are shifting by 1/2 of the width of your object on both sides** (minimum and maximum return value).

So to use this function, take your object, lets say a UILabel and set its center to this functions result as such:

```
let myLabel = UIButton(type: .Custom)
myLabel.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)
myLabel.center = randomizeLocation(myLabel.bounds)
```

And that it. Btw, I did not account for the -1 in the return b/c i figured the one pixel was too insignificant to bother with..